# A question from a recruitment agent - answer or not

Tags: recruitment, human-resources

I'm new to HR and recruitment process by means of using a recruitment agent. One of them actually sent me a CV which we had received from a different agency. However, that's not a problem, but might serve as an explanation for his following question, which was whether I could submit a list of names of candidates whose CVs we have already received from all agencies we use. I'm not willing to provide the agent with those names as I think that's up to a candidate to reveal whether they are with more than one agency and whatever data we have received so far is confidential. But, can a recruitment agent actually ask for this sort of information?
Thank you for any advice

Comment: I think this is a question for your manager, don't you think?

Comment: As a candidate, I would not appreciate this. I manage my relations with recruiters. If they need me, they can find me at linked-in or via someone who me personally, not this way.

Answer (score 6):

The agent can ask for anything. Doesn't mean that they're allowed to have it.

If you give a list of all candidates to an agency (regardless of the source of those candidates), then you've just given them a wonderful list of warm leads to contact with job opportunities. Ignoring the very essential privacy issue (if I give you my resume, I'm assuming you'll only pass it on to people who need to have it), why should you do the recruiters job for them, with no reward to yourself?

Comment: Some agents will go to all sorts of lengths to get their candidates in front of you, and harvest new candidates. This includes lying to my colleagues, sending CVs that they weren't authorised to send, sending fake CVs for non-existent candidates, pressuring HR into on-site meetings and then trying to snoop round the office... always be wary with an agent and never take anything at face value until you've established a decent working relationship with them, there's enough scumbags out there that you will experience one sooner or later.

Comment: Julia: Don't hold back, say what you think! (actually, I agree with everything you said, I was just trying to be a little more nice :) ....)

Answer (score 4):

> his following question, which was whether I could submit a list of
>   names of candidates whose CVs we have already received from all
>   agencies we use. I'm not willing to provide the agent with those names
>   as I think that's up to a candidate to reveal whether they are with
>   more than one agency and whatever data we have received so far is
>   confidential. But, can a recruitment agent actually ask for this sort
>   of information?

The agent can ask for pretty much anything, but that doesn't impose an obligation on you.

While you could give him the list, that's not something I'd do. I agree with you that it's up to the agent and candidate to work together and decide if they choose to be exclusive or not, and how to deal with multiple submissions.

Instead, you could tell the agent that you'll let him/her know if you have already received that candidate through a different agent if that's what you would prefer.

Some companies have a strict "first one to present a candidate wins" policy. Others have tiered approach where only Tier 1 vendors have a shot until after a certain period of time.

Comment: Revealing to anyone who doesn't need to know that someone is applying for a job is a breach of confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

Agency can ask a lot of things.  Up to you to decide if you are going to reply.  You should have some kind of record of when the first resume was received.

If you simply reply we already received a resume for that candidate on yy-mm-dd then hopefully that is enough.

If the recruiter demands proof and which agency then you need to decide the relationship with that recruiter.

The agreement between the applicant and the recruiter is between the applicant and the recruiter.